# Saving data to database through Data Grid

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2012, dataset

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_gym_staff_salary_gym_staff_info". The conflict occurred in database "D:\GYM MANAGEMENT SYSTEM\GYM MANAGEMENT SYSTEM\BIN\DEBUG\GMSDATABASE.MDF", table "dbo.gym_staff_info", column 'Id'.
```

I am getting this error while saving data to database using data grid view, I have implemented data grid view from the following tutorial

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171890.aspx

The problem it is pointing to is I guess the foreign key. I am attaching a pic in this picture I am trying to save data but when I click a yellow plus button at the top I get "-1" in Id column, and I can not edit it I think that is the problem How do I edit it? And if I can not how can i solve this error? All help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your grid editable? If not make it. Then do so. Another thing on the click of plus button just add row and debug and check why the column id is showing -1.

Comment: Yes grid is editable. and now i have changed that -1 from Data Set designer it was set to readonly=true; and autoincrement=-1; but I am still getting that error and it is not saving data.

Comment: On adding new row check and delete any value in your code. That may help you solve your problem.

Comment: Can you please explain?